# send a value from the child component to the parent component reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a screen with a TAB, that TAB is a component and within the TAB there is another component called FORM.

hierarchy:

- SCREEN

  - TAB

    - FORM

in this hierarchy, I want to pass the NAME value from the FORM component to the TAB component and then from the TAB component to the SCREEN component.

Code Screen:

```
export default function Screen() {
  return (
    <>
      <TabProfile me={me} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Code TAB:

```
export default function TabProfile({ me }) {
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.demo1}>
        <AntTabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="ant example">
          <AntTab label="Config" />
        </AntTabs>
      </div>
      <div>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
          <Config me={!me ? [] : me} />
        </TabPanel>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code FORM:

```
export default function Config({ me }) {
  return (
    <>
      <BoxFormGrid>
        <Label>Name</Label>
        <Input type="text" value={name} />
      </BoxFormGrid>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by having a state in your top component. Then you pass the state update function down twice:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Screen() {
  const [ name, setName ] = useState('me') // 'me' is the start value

  return (
    <>
      <TabProfile me={name} setName={setName} />
    </>
  );
}
```

```
export default function TabProfile({ me, setName }) {
  return (...
          <Config me={!me ? [] : me} setName={setName} />
  ...
  );
}
```

```
export default function Config({ me, setName }) {
  return (
    <>
      <BoxFormGrid>
        <Label>Name</Label>
        <Input type="text" value={me} onChange={event => setName(event.target.value)} />
      </BoxFormGrid>
    </>
  );
}
```